# How to execute JavaScript from file

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, code-injection

I am trying to launch a webpage in Firefox browser using python-Selenium web driver and to inject java script code on that loaded page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver= webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.python.org")
```

by the above code webpage is launched. Now my requirement is to add the js code to it.

```
driver.execute_script('''alert("java Script injected");''')
```

adding the above line to the code inject the single line js to webpage creating a dialog box showing "java Script injected".

What I actually want is to inject a Java Script code written in a file named jscode.js to the webpage launched using selenium web driver in python language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute JavaScript from file, try below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver= webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.python.org")

with open('/path/to/jscode.js') as f:
    java_script = f.read()

driver.execute_script(java_script)
```